# Python Bytewise reading from real time data source

Tags: python, bluetooth, serial-port, byte, real-time

I have developed a hardware which scans real time Analog Signal through ADC(12bit) and sends it a receiver via Bluetooth. To make real time signal acquisition with little latency, I transmitted the ADC values in byte chunks (MSB first and LSB in the next for each values). I was able to read and reconstruct each ADC value with Java. But Data Visualization is a bit tricky and time consuming coding in java. So, I am planning to switch to Python which has rich Data visualization modules like matplotlib, pyQtGraph.

Please name me some free serial communication libraries (python, free and well documented) that can read data byte wise.

Comment: SO is a place to ask for help with specific coding problems. This requires you to provide code. Asking for recommendations on software libraries is explicitly off topic. Please read through the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section.

Comment: pyserial has always done the trick

Comment: @stevieb: I will ask coding specific questions, if I face any problems while coding with pyserial (the recommended one, at this point). Thanks for reminding me the rules, anyway.

Comment: You should consider deleting this question until you've had a crack with `pyserial` (it does work well by the way), and ask a new, on-topic question if you run into specific programming question.